# Disable multiple RDP sessions in windows server

Tags: rdp, terminal-server

By default windows will allow two RDP sessions. I need to disable two session operation & allow only one session to access the windows server.

Thank you !

Comment: Have you had a chance to check this solution? https://support.managed.com/kb/a1816/how-to-enable-disable-multiple-rdp-sessions-in-windows-2012.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Open `gpedit.msc`, then go to

`Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections`.

Double click the `Limit number of connections` and set the RD Maximum Connections allowed to `1`.

Make sure the `Restrict Remote Desktop Services user to a single Remote Desktop Services session` is set to `Enabled`

Comment: Just a small addition. This only works with "Remote Desktop Services" and **not** with "Remote Desktop" (the 2 sessions for admin access).